# Disable event theme during event in tetris 99

Tags: nintendo-switch, tetris-99

I'm visually impaired, and I find that many of the newer themes have a bad colour contrast, especially with the ghost block. So even during events, I'd like to keep using the default theme in online battles. Is that possible?